# How to select last order_no and order_date for particular Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to select last order_no and order_date for group by (customer_key)

DATA TABLE NAME Cust_order
Order_id    Order_no        Order_date  Customer_key
1         FL/BSR/130221/21  13.02.21    1233325
2         FL/BDR/080321/69  08.03.21    550089
3         FL/BSR/210322/30  21.03.22    1233325
4         FL/BSR/161221/28  16.12.21    1233325
5         FL/GZL/300722/33  30.07.22    1239689
6         FL/BDR/080220/52  08.02.20    550089
7         FL/GZL/231221/54  23.12.21    1239689
8         FL/GZL/190422/66  19.04.22    1239689

OUTPUT TABLE
Order_no           Order_date   Customer_key
FL/BDR/080321/69    08.03.21    550089
FL/BSR/210322/30    21.03.22    1233325
FL/GZL/300722/33    30.07.22    1239689

My probable query as below

select Customer_key, max(Order_date) as DATE
from Cust_order
WHERE  Customer_key in (1233325,550089,1239689)
group by Customer_key

But I am unable to select last Order_no according to last Order_date for the customer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_key ORDER BY Order_date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Customer_key IN (1233325, 550089, 1239689) 
)

SELECT Order_no, Order_date, Customer_key
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: The query is working fine and unnecessarily generating 15000 rows for my cust_order table. So row_number will not work here because I have to generate the query on specific customer_key or a range of order_date.

Comment: I missed that requirement; check the updated query above.

Comment: Now it is working as per my requirement.